# I am unable to get Login button detected via IDE

Tags: eclipse

I am a begineer at selenium. recorded a login page using Selenium IDE. When playing ths recorded scrip, it is not able to detect Login button on screen.

**Command IDE recorded >>**

```
Click      id=loginForm:loginButton
```

**Piece of code, I am inspecting via FireBug is**

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left: -20px;">
<button id="loginForm:loginButton" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only span9 btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'loginForm:loginButton',update:'loginForm'});return false;" name="loginForm:loginButton" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Login</span>
</button>
</div>
```

I have tried so many possibilities but unable to get Login button detected by IDE.